# SSMS throws System.OutOfMemoryException on every query

Tags: sql, memory-leaks, ssms

I've been running into some performance issues in SSMS recently, hanging and slow downs but now I'm starting to see any query I run throw an out of memory exception. Even something as simple as "SELECT TOP 1 1" will not return any results. Looking at the task manager it doesn't look like SSMS is hitting it's 2BG memory cap, and I'm still under 50% total usage.

[image]
The issue is resolved by restarting SSMS so could this be some memory leak problem?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: 2016:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.16106.4

Comment: Unless you need something that was removed from SSMS 18 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#deprecated-and-removed-features-in-180), I recommend you install SSMS 18 and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same issue but I've noticed a serious memory leak issue with SSMS (although a later version - 17.4) which is something to do with the SQL content itself.

In my case, an EXECUTE command with a large number of parameters (90+) is causing the leak when part of a larger stored procedure of around 700+ lines.

Upon pasting this command into the procedure, the memory hits the allocation limit within a few seconds and SSMS becomes almost totally unresponsive.

**EDIT:** I narrowed this down to a COALESCE statement in one the parameters of the stored procedure call. The memory leak is triggered as soon as I type the keyword COALESCE, before I've even finished writing the statement.

```
@price,
@opening,
@closing,
@issue_price,
coalesce(@ticker, @symbol), 
@isin,                      
@cusip,                         
@sedol,
```

It only seems to occur as part of a larger procedure call though.
Note that in my case, the same issue happens when loading the file into Visual Studio 2019 16.0.1.